# how to count word by word and not character by character in python

Tags: python, string, list

I need to write a code which recognizes special names such as names for places and people cities and etc.
and then it should announce the place of the word and not character.
for example if the string is:
'Today Sam and Martin are happy'
it should print out this:
1:Sam
3:Martin
but my code writes:
0:Today
6:Sam
14:Martin
here is the actual code:

```
import re
b=[]
x=str(input())
r =re.compile('([A-Z][a-z]+)')
a=re.findall(r, x) 
a=list(a)
word=len(x.split())
b=[word for word in range(len(x)) if x[word].isupper()]
o=str([j for i in zip(b,a) for j in i])
d=o.replace(", '", ':').replace("'",'').replace(",", '\n').replace('[','').replace(']', 
'').replace(' ', '')
print(d)
```

do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: `it should print out this: 1:Sam 4:Martin` ... _Why_ should this be printed?  Can you add an explanation to your question?

Comment: `[print(str(i+1) + ":" + j, end=" ") for i,j in enumerate(x.split())]`

Comment: To add any other explanation I should say that 'Sam' is the second word and 'Martin'  is the fourth word because python's counting function starts counting from 0. that's why it should be counted like that. Also,Thank you Alexander for the help.